# How to batch create filenames in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder

I am running a model in ModelBuilder. The input are raster files in *.tiff format and the output are *.asc format.

I am using iterate raster and there will be 365 input and output files using %name%.asc

e.g input file : LST01011990.tiff  --> output file LST01011990.tiff.asc

How I can output the filename to LST01011990.asc (without repeating the *.tiff)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the model only tool called [Parse Path](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//004000000008000000).

1. Right-click on the ModelBuilder screen > Model Only Tools > Parse
   Path.
2. Make sure to select the "NAME" Parse Type, which will pass on 
   "LST01011990" to the next tool
3. Connect "Value" to the next tool as a precondition, so that the name
   is parsed before the [Raster to ASCII](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001200000005000000) is run
4. Call the raster name in the raster to ascii tool via `%Value%`.

[image]