# Viewshed over Multiple DEM Models Possible?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, dem, viewshed

I finally got the viewshed working correctly over one DEM model. However, I am wondering is it possible to do the viewshed over multiple DEMs? E.g. A Multiple County Viewshed based off one point.

The dataset source does not allow downloads over 2gb. So I'm forced to download each county separately. I think a vaguely remember a way to combine rasters. If that is possible, which tool do I use ?

Comment: Viewshed will only work on a single continuous raster (from a observer point located on the raster, not somewhere else), so you'll definitely need to mosaic it as Chris W describes.

Comment: @Erica Is that entirely correct? I was under the impression you could also run it on a mosaic dataset, which is not actually a single contiguous raster though the tools treat it as such. I ask because I've not used that method myself. And I believe there *is* a distinction between a mosaic (which won't work) and a mosaic dataset (new at 10.0), as mentioned at [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67085/problem-creating-a-raster-mosaic-to-run-a-viewshed-analysis?rq=1).

Comment: I more meant to comment that it couldn't be run on multiple separate raster files, or with the point somewhere that's not on the DEM. If you mosaic them to a new raster, it works fine. I haven't tried running them on a mosaic dataset either.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you're looking for [Mosaic to New Raster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000098000000) in the Raster toolset. It may take some fiddling depending on how well adjacent DEMs overlap/line up. If you're running into file download limits at 2GB, you may also end up running into a problem with your output raster being too large depending how many pieces you have to combine. This may require piecing fewer together at once, or possibly seeking a lower resolution DEM depending on how large an area you're trying to cover. Or just being very patient with processing times. :)

Another option would be to create a [Mosaic dataset](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009t00000037000000) out of your individual rasters. This keeps the files separate rather than merging to one huge file, but the tool treats it as a single file. Relevant [Esri Blog post](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/03/11/mosaic-datasets-the-new-way-to-view-analyze-and-manage-military-rasters/).